# HLS H264/AAC stream functions perfectly except on OS X and iOS?

Tags: streaming, h.264, aac, mpeg2-ts

We are developing an open-source streaming server and are running into some trouble with our implementation of HLS.

We've been able to successfully convert to TS and segment into HLS segments any stream we want to, and it plays back beautifully on most every player... except for the Apple players (iPad, iPhone, Safari, Quicktime). On those, the H264 encoding settings need to be picked very carefully, and even when sticking to Baseline/3.0 some visible glitching can be seen.

The AAC audio, no matter how we encode it (both ffmpeg's aac and the libfkd_aac encoders were tried in nearly all possible configurations) sounds choppy as well. (Again, all these versions play back just fine on non-Apple players.) Changing the encoding settings does yield better results sometimes, but we've not been able to find any combination that will work for every video we've been testing with.

This leads us to conclude that perhaps the Apple-based players require something in the TS stream itself that we're not doing correctly. Is there anything that could cause this kind of behavior? For reference, an HLS teststream outputted by our packager/segmenter can be found here: [link](http://gary.ddvtech.com:8080/hls/bunny/index.m3u8)

We appreciate any feedback!

Comment: have you tried segmenter provided by apple itself. i think apple also provide somekind of stream validator for HLS.

Comment: Dear Rajneesh, yes, but we *have* to implement the segmenter ourselves. Their validator seems to like our stream more than their own test stream ( http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbopall.html ), which doesn't even validate. Working on a raw data comparison between a validly segmented stream and ours right now, though. Regards